# Name in one2many field form does not same with name in input field

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, one2many

I have created a related field on the custom payroll form and I use odoo 10. I can not get the same name in one2many form field with input field.

I have attached picture in below. Hope in here, I want to make the name in black pen same with the name in blue pen. But in the picture, I can't get the name from blue pen show in the black pen.

[image: problem]

Here my code :

```
gaji.py
  emp_id = fields.Many2one('karyawan', 'Karyawan')

karyawan.py
  nama = fields.Char(string="Nama Karyawan")
  gaji_ids = fields.One2many('gaji', 'emp_id', 'Gaji')

karyawan_view.xml
   <page string="Gaji" name="gaji">
                        <field name="gaji_ids" context="{'default_emp_id':nama}" widget="one2many_list">
                            <tree editable="bottom">
                                <field name="emp_id" attrs="{'readonly': [('emp_id', '!=', False)]}"/>
                                <field name="gaji_pokok"/>
                                <field name="jumlah_hari_kerja"/>                                    
                                <field name="jumlah_kerja"/>  
                                <field name="libur"/>                                                                      
                                <field name="jam_lembur"/>                                    
                                <field name="t_lembur"/>
                                <field name="t_transportasi"/>
                                <field name="total_pendapatan"/>
                            </tree>
                        </field>
                    </page>
```

Anyone can help me about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename field name `nama` to `name` in `karyawan.py`

karyawan.py

```py
name = fields.Char(string="Nama Karyawan")
```

In `many2one` field, the system will fetch value of `name` field in a comodel. If field `name` doesn't exist will display model name with id (karyawan,2).

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different field labels:

```py
emp_id = fields.Many2one('karyawan', 'Karyawan')  # second parameter is the label
```

and

```py
nama = fields.Char(string="Nama Karyawan")  # string parameter is the label
```

So change one of the two.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your model

```
 _rec_name= 'nama'
```

nama = fields.Char(string="Nama Karyawan")
  gaji_ids = fields.One2many('gaji', 'emp_id', 'Gaji')